# Modifying object from not void function

Tags: java, class, function, void

I have some problems with my Java class. When I call function (for exmaple int getCapacity(Edge e)) it changes my object (chagne Edge e) and I don't want to do that. Shouldn't only void functions change objects? Any help?

```
public class Edge{

    private int start;

    private int end;

    private int capacity;  

    private int flow;  

    public Edge(int p, int k, int cap) {
        this.start = p;
        this.end = k;
        this.capacity = cap;
        this.flow=0;
    }

    public void setStart(int s){
            this.start = s;
    }


    public static int getCapacity(Edge e){
            e.setStart(-1);
            return e.capacity;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Edge e= new Edge();
        int k=getCapacity(e));
        e.print();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't only void functions change objects?

Not necessarily. A very simple example of this is `StringBuilder`, where almost all methods return `this`, so you can write:

```
builder.append(x).append(y);
```

However, it *is* surprising to make a getter modify state. That sounds like a bad idea to me. It's not clear why you *are* changing the start in this particular case, but surely you can just change your method to not do that.

Even that rule can *occasionally* be wrong though. A simple example of this is an LRU-cache, where fetching data from it *does* affect state, as it will change which records are retained when the cache overflows. That's relatively rare though.

It's also unclear why `getCapacity` is a static method. Beware static methods with a parameter of the same type as the declaring class. Unless it's deliberately like that to cope with null references (which this isn't) you should usually change them to be instance methods.

Comment: I just dont want to change my objects from not void function. I inserted a part of code " e.setStart(-1);" just to test it.

And about getter, I need it later. ;) In other classes.

Comment: another example is an iterator. it will change it's state for every call and return a value.

Comment: @newOne: Fine, don't do so - but it's not *incorrect* code to do so.

Comment: Function public static int getCapacity(Edge e) shouldn't change argument Edge e whatever I'm doing inside it's body (function body).
I can do whatever I want, function just should return me a valeu (int) not change Edge, that's the problem!

I'm starting loosing my nervs :)

Comment: @newOne: So fix the code so it doesn't do that. You're in charge of the code, right? It's up to you to make sure it doesn't do anything stupid.